# Laravel 5.5 localization for login routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a problem with the default auth routes of the new Laravel version. I used the function:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

After that I moved all the default routes to the routes/web.php and they are in the Localization group:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(), 'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect' ]], function() {

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth'], function () {

    $this->get('login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'LoginController@login');
    $this->post('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('register', 'RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    $this->post('register', 'RegisterController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
     $this->post('password/email', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'ResetPasswordController@reset');

});
// other frontend routes
});
```

Unfortunately when i call php artisan route:list i do not see the 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect' Middlewares.

Middleware:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'localize' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRoutes::class,
    'localizationRedirect' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter::class,
    'localeSessionRedirect' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleSessionRedirect::class,
    'localeViewPath' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationViewPath::class,
];
```

Any suggestions how to fix that ?

Comment: @Webinion The inner group is not for middleware it is just a namespace group.

Comment: @Webinion that doesn't help either

Comment: Have you assigned `localeSessionRedirect` into the Kernel.php?

Comment: @Option it is assigned. I noticed that when i open /en/login it shows me the correct page, but when i display the login link with route('login') it returns just /login that's the whole problem

Comment: @Vince, I am surprised it's allowing you to see it to be honest as you have the get and post to login etc wrapped inside the Auth middleware. Anything within the Auth middleware is generally once the user has been signed in.

Comment: @Option it is not Auth middleware. It is a Namespace !

Comment: Oh yah my mistake misread xD

Comment: Show you mware for the setlocal

Comment: @Option i made an edit for the middleware

Comment: that's your kernel.php. We need to see the code for: 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect'